# database schema object abstraction

Tags: database, oop, schema

I am creating abstraction of database schema using object oriented programming. I have a design issue: should indices be top-level objects (like tables, view, stored procedures) or rather should be accessible through a table, like columns? What about triggers too?

I am building a python package (http://code.google.com/p/fathom/) for database schema discovery. Right now indices are accessed through table, but I see that some tools for administering database have indices as separate entry in some tree view, just like tables. That's why I am wondering, If I am doing it right.

Comment: Can you explain the reasons why you're not using an ORM?

Comment: @Neil: I have asked a question whether I should try doing it in programmers.se.com. Now I am asking something different. @Paul: See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Indices" are part of a single table like "columns", they are not independent, like a S.P. where the developer can alter o modify several tables.

They are composed by several columns or expressions from a single table.

In the other hand, I agree sometimes its confusing. Many tools put relations among tables as dependant on a single table, and I prefer to think relations as an item of the database, not as a single table, just the opposite of "indices".